# Is a subset of a sphere that is itself contained within a hemisphere totally convex?

Tags: convex-analysis, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

This question has been bugging me for awhile since some papers claim it is, and others do not. Suppose $M \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is a sphere and sub manifold of 3D Euclidean space. Let $x$ be the North Pole, and suppose I have a geodesic ball $B$ centered at $x$ that is itself contained within the upper hemisphere. Is this set totally convex? My intuition says yes, because all geodesics whose endpoints are in $B$ are clearly contained in $B$. All geodesics are arcs of great circles, after all.

However, the textbook Convex Functions and Convex Optimization Methods" claimed that "in a sphere. any proper subset is not totally convex." Can someone point out my misunderstanding?

Comment: What does "totally convex" mean?

Comment: And (more to the point) are the definitions of "totally convex" that occur in all of those different papers equivalent to each other?

Comment: I have never heard of the term totally convex, except maybe in San Fernando Valley.

Comment: To me, $A$ is totally convex means "if $p,q\in A$, any geodesic segment $[p,q]$ is in $A$". And the answer is no in this case. But this can have lots of different meanings, like "[...] there exists a geodesic segment [...]" and in that case, it would be yes. Or "[...] any **minimizing** geodesic segment [...]", and it would be yes again.

Comment: @Didier can you explain why the answer is no in the first case? What other geodesic would there be? The curve in the opposite direction of the sphere isn't a geodesic since it's not locally minimizing length?

Comment: @LeeMosher What do you mean different papers? I only referenced a single textbook?

Comment: @copper.hat A subset $A \subset M$ is totally convex if all geodesics whose endpoints are in $A$ are themselves contained in $A$.

Comment: @SpencerKraisler There are two geodesic segments from $p$ to $q$: the little part of the great circle passing through $p$ and $q$ (which is minimizing), and the bigger part of that same great circle. The latter always escapes from the selected hemisphere

Comment: @Didier regarding the bigger part, that isn't a local minimum of the length functional, no? I can imagine a variation of that curve (i.e. the curve slides a bit to the left) where we have a resulting curve with less length. My understanding is a geodesic is a local min of the length functional, and that curve doesn't seem to be a local minimum.

Comment: It is a geodesic since it satisfies the equation of geodesics $\nabla_{\gamma'}\gamma' = 0$, implying that it is an extremal of the length functional. Everything depends on your definition of geodesic. Also, it locally minimizes the distance between any close enough points in its support

Comment: You wrote "some papers claim it is, and others do not", so I was asking what papers you were referring to.